# SQL Alchemy: how to work with NOT NULL clause

Tags: python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

In the following, executable source code I have a small problem. Well you can see, that I set the `nullable` on False in the column named `some_text`. When I run this program, enter all necessary registration data correctly, and at the place where I should enter a text, but I just pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>, I get no error message. I thought, when I just press enter (no text, empty item), so I will get an error message from SQLAlchemy. But nothing happened. SQLAlchemy simply executes the `commit ()`. After that when I working with `MySQL WorkBench`, an empty entry is present in the database.

Did I do something wrong?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

''' setting up root class for declarative declaration '''
Base = declarative_base()

class SOME_TEXT(Base):

    __tablename__ = "some_text"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    some_text = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, Some_text):

        self.some_text = Some_text

def main():
    try:
        dbms = raw_input('Enter database type: ')
        dbdriver = raw_input('Enter database driver: ')
        dbuser = raw_input('Enter user name: ')
        dbuser_pwd = raw_input('Enter user password: ')
        db_server_host = raw_input('Enter server host: ')
        dbport = raw_input('Enter port: ')
        db_name = raw_input('Enter database name: ')

        url = '{}+{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
               dbms, dbdriver, dbuser, dbuser_pwd, db_server_host, dbport, db_name)

        ''' Create the engine '''
        engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)

        ''' Create the schema and tables '''
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

        ''' Create the Session class '''
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

        ''' Create a new Session '''
        session = Session()

        ''' Populate the database '''
        enter_text = raw_input('Enter text: ')
        some_text_table = SOME_TEXT(enter_text)
        session.add(some_text_table)

        ''' Commit the changes: '''
        session.commit()

    except SQLAlchemyError as err:
        print "err", err


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you don't enter anything, you get the empty string (`""`), not `None`, which satisfies the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: You were right, univerio. TA.